# Bash sed command to delete all lines matched within a parameter for in Android

Tags: android, linux, bash, sed, parameters

I'm stuck with my sed command to delete all matches and parameters of the match within the file. I've tried many different combinations but I can't quite get a command that does what I need.

This is my sed command:

```
sed -i '/test {/,/}/d' $FILE
```

And this is my match I'm trying to delete:

```
  test {
    library proxy
    uuid 9d4921da-8225-4f29-aefa-6e6f69726861

    libsw {
      library test_sw
      uuid 6ab06da4-c516-4611-8166-6168726e6f69
    }

    libhw {
      library test_hw
      uuid a0c30891-8246-4aef-b8ad-696f6e726861
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately my command results in the lines from above not being deleted:

```
     libhw {
      library test_hw
      uuid a0c30891-8246-4aef-b8ad-696f6e726861
    }
  }
```

My command works and deletes the entire match/parameters for:

```
  test {
    library test
    uuid f1c02420-777f-11e3-981f-0800200c9a66
  }
```

I would be very thankful to get some insight in what I am doing wrong and perhaps fix to help me solve this issue.

Comment: Please show expected input and output. Also don't use `-i` to test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using GNU sed

```
sed -z 's/test {[^{}]*\({[^}]*}[^{}]*\)*}//g' testfile
```

`-z` tells sed to read in all characters in the file up to the first NUL character.  Since no sensible source/text file has a NUL characters, this is the same as reading in the whole file.

The substitute command removes the text that you want to delete.  In more detail:

- `test {[^{}]*` matches the `test {` string followed by any number of non-curly-brace characters.
- `\({[^}]*}[^{}]*\)*` matches any number of groups, `\(...\)`, consisting of an open curly brace, `{`, any number of non-curly-braces, `[^}]*`, followed by a closing curly-brace, `}`, followed by any number of non-curly-braces, `[^{}]*`.
- `}` matches the closing curly-brace that corresponds to the opening brace in `test {`.

#### Using other sed

If we are using a sed that does not support the `-z` flag, then we need to add commands to read in multiple lines at once.  For example:

```
sed  'H;1h;$!d;x; s/test {[^{}]*\({[^}]*}[^{}]*\)*}//g' testfile
```

#### Deleting as well the line containing the last }

This variation will (a) remove all blank space before `text {` and also (b) remove all blank space on the line after the closing `}` along with the newline that follows it:

```
sed  'H;1h;$!d;x; s/[[:blank:]]*test {[^{}]*\({[^}]*}[^{}]*\)*}[[:blank:]]*\n//g' file
```

#### Using awk

```
awk '/test {/{f=1; n=0} !f{print} {n+=gsub(/{/,"{", $0)-gsub(/}/,"}",$0)} n==0{f=0}' testfile
```

Here, the variable `f` keeps track of when we are in a `test` block.  The variable `n` keeps track of how many open `{` there are.  Once we enter a `test` block, this stop printing until the last open `{` is closed.

- `/test {/ {f=1; n=0}`

  When we reach a line with that contains the characters `test {`, we set `f` to one and `n` to zero.
- `!f{print}`

  If `f` is zero, the we print the line.
- `n+=gsub(/{/,"{", $0) - gsub(/}/,"}",$0)`

  This updates the count of open `{`.  `gsub(/{/,"{", $0)` returns the number of `{` while `gsub(/}/,"}",$0)` returns the number of `}`.  We subtract these two numbers to get the net change in open braces.
- `n==0 {f=0}`

  When the open brace count goes down to zero, we set `f` to zero to indicate the completion of the `test {` group.

Comment: Other sed worked partially. First, this is a script an external script file not within the $test file so the sed command output within the script file rather than changing the $test file itself. The command also kept the space before the last } instead of deleting the entire line.

Comment: @AhrionGallegos If you want to change the file in-place, you can use the `-i` option with `sed`.  To change a file in-place with awk, assuming that you have a modern GNU awk, then add the option `-i inplace`.  If this was not what you were asking, please clarify.

Comment: I can't execute awk unfortunately. However I'm trying to change an existing file from a command line in a separate file, which is the command we're speaking of. So I'm executing the command to patch an external file. So this would be in place right? sed -i 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/test {[^{}]*\({[^}]*}[^{}]*\)*}//g' $VENDOR_CONFIG has a "sed no temp file" error

Comment: _"I'm trying to change an existing file from a command line in a separate file"_  That should work just fine with `sed -i ....`.   I just tested `sed -i 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/test {[^{}]*\({[^}]*}[^{}]*\)*}//g' testfile` on an android and it worked just as it should.

Comment: Oh my gosh it I didn't mount my storage. It did work.  Instead of deleteing the last line containing "  }", it deleted the } but left the "  " space and the line. How do I delete the line containing the last } as well as the space? You're a lifesaver by the way. Never realized how insanely confusing these sed commands are in co.parison to awk or generic Java code.

Comment: EDIT: It could be the first part s/test as well since it also contains empty space. Would it be better to just have the command delete the next line? If so what are the command opstions for that?

Comment: @AhrionGallegos I just added to the answer code to remove the surrounding blank space and the newline after the closing `}`.  I think that will do what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk  '/test {/{a=1} /{/ {f++} f==0&&a==1{a=0} /}/{f--} a==0{print}' file
```